# Livewire - Should I fetch data from database in mount method or render method?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have 2 components:

- Websites: To fetch all websites (~300 websites) from the database.
- DetailWebsite: To display detailed info of a website when a user selects it on the list.

I did 2 tests:

In the first test, I fetched 300 websites in the `mount` method and assign the result to `public $websites`. Then I click a website on the list to view detail, it takes ~2s to reload the `Websites` component then it loads the `DetailWebsite` component after that.

```
public function mount()
{
    $this->fetchWebsites();
}

public function fetchWebsites() {.....}
```

[image]

But in the 2nd test, I fetched data and pass to the view in `render` method.

```
public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.guest-posts', ['websites' => $this->fetchWebsites()]);
}
```

It only takes 800ms-1.5s (The time will have a big difference if I increase the items in the database). Why it can be faster than the 1st test since the `mount` method only runs one time at initial while render will be run every time I click a website to view detail.

This is my function to get the website detail:

```
public function selectWebsite($websiteId)
{
    $this->selectedWebsiteId = $websiteId;
    $this->emitTo('detail-website', 'findWebsite', $websiteId);
}
```

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but I would personally use defered loading for this https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/defer-loading

Comment: I make myself the same question. 
In my case, I need to load data from several models, in order to use that for select lists. So I thought that we could get a better performance if data is loaded in mount() method, because those queries run just once.